# Populating Large TextFields using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, textfield, multiline

I'm populating an already existing PDF MultiLine TextField with possibly a small or large amount of text.  I have two textfields that are separated across two pages.  Is there a way to have text overflow into the second textfield after the first is filled up.

I know that setting the font size to 0 will make iTextSharp to try and fit the text, but there some instances where there is to much text and it needs to continue on a second page.

As far as I can tell, I cant even figure out if the existing textfield has overflowed or not.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write your own jquery / javascript script to change the textbox foxus after the length of the first value reaches a certain length?

Comment: I'm populating the textfields from a database.

Comment: @FARNK: Then simply bind the first inputtext to a SUBSTRING of the value up to the max and bind the SUBSTRING from the max to the entire length of the string.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  I have a string.  Using iTextSharp I can assign the text to the textfield.  I'm looking for a somewhat easy way to even tell if I have  reached the max of the field. Max Characters wont work since there are newlines. Ect and possible diff. font size in the future.

Comment: @FARNK: I'm trying to suggest you split it up in the database before it gets to the textboxes. A column for the maximum amount of text you can hold in the textbox, a second column for the remainder. This is fairly straightforward if you use the SQL SUBSTRING operator during your data retrieval.

Comment: Sorry, for the misunderstanding, but how in iTextSharp can I tell my maximum length for the first textbox.  Thats where I'm having the issue.  I can't split them up until I know what my max is for the first textbox.  I know there is a max character count, but this doesn't take into account, new lines and poss. different font sizes.